# can a parent confiscate his dependent child's property?

Tags: children-parenting, gezel-stealing

If a child is over bar mitzva and dependent on the parent, may the latter confiscate his child's possessions as a form of punishment or would this be considered damage/theft

I am not asking on property which belongs to the father but rather something that belongs solely to the son such as a gift given specifically to him.

Comment: If you ask  hilchaty,  of course.  When a son,  even adult  is eating and sleeping at the father  home there is a takanat chachomim. So maybe that a part of the  son property is not really his property and may be confiscated

Comment: See BM 12b, what is confiscation from an Halachic point of view.